# Check Android Permissions in a Method

Tags: android, annotations, coding-style, lint, error-suppression

here is my code and it *works perfectly fine*.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

But I don't like such a big code on every check, and want to delegate it to a method in my utility class.

```
if (Utils.hasMapLocationPermissions(getActivity())) {
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

But `setMyLocationEnabled` has annotation `@RequiresPermission` And thus I can't delegate it to a method, because **lint** and **editor** shows it as an **error**.

Is there some annotation to write on my utility method and suppress lint?

Something like this

```
@ChecksPermission
public boolean hasMapLocationPermissions(Activity activity) {
  return // my checking logic..
}
```

Comment: Try putting `setMyLocationEnabled` in a `try-catch` and handle `SecurityException`. Should work without annotation.

Comment: The code is still big and looks ugly. I want to solve with neat small code.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can rename your method such as `checkLocationPermission(Activity activity)`. I´ve discovered that your method's name must start with "check" and end with "Permission" to pass Lint warnings.

For example:

```
public static boolean checkLocationPermission(Context context) {
    return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

Comment: For me only the `checkPermission()` method name works.

Answer (score 17):

You can suppress this error in both the editor and in lint reports by annotating your method with `@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")`, or you can suppress the error for just a single statement by putting `//noinspection MissingPermission` above that line.

For example:

```
@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
public boolean hasMapLocationPermissions(Activity activity) {
  // your checking logic
}
```

Or:

```
if (Utils.hasMapLocationPermissions(getActivity())) {
    //noinspection MissingPermission
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```